# How old is earth according to Hinduism?

Tags: belief, scripture, yuga

I'm just curious to know, How old is earth according to hinduism?

As of science it is  4,500,000,000.

If we calculate this 4.5 billion years into Hinduism, 1041 Mahayugas, which is equal to 1 kalpa i.e 1 day of lord Brahma. But as of Hinduism, 50 years of lord Brahma have elapsed and this is the first 'day' of the 51<sup>st</sup> year.

According to Hinduism calculations based on age of lord brahma, age of earth must be 155,521,972,949,115 years. If lord brahma created earth on his first day of his birth.

I found one [link](http://www.religioustolerance.org/ev_date1.htm) which states, according to Hinduism earth is created and destroyed for regular intervals of time. Is that true?

- Are there any texts that mention about age of earth in Hinduism? Or
- Did Hinduism mention when and where it was created (any belief)?

Please give brief explanation on this topic.

Comment: Yes Hinduism does talk about a creation and liberation concept after every interval. http://www.bhagavad-gita.org/Gita/verse-09-07.html.

Comment: 1. It is correct that the universe is created and destroyed in mahapralaya and created again.   2. See this for calculation of the universe's age http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_cosmology But remember that this is only for the current Brahma's reign. Noone knows how many Brahma's preceded the current one and how many are forthcoming. For information, Lord Anjaneya is the next Brahma. There are already two Indras-in-waiting, viz, Bali Chakravarti and Raja Harischandra.

Comment: @moonstar2001 that's interesting. I would love to see some source regarding "Lord Anjaneya is the next Brahma"

Comment: @moonstar2001 "Noone knows how many Brahma's preceded the current one and how many are forthcoming." This chapter of the Shanti Parva of the Mahabharata describes six Mahakalpas before the present one, but of course that may not be exhaustive: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c048.htm

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan That is perhaps only the extent to which sages have chosen to reveal to the world. Scriptures also indicate that the skull-garland around Siva's and Kali's neck are actually skulls of Brahmas-past and are said to be infinite in number.

Comment: @moonstar2001 What scripture says that?

Answer (score 9):

Time between begining of creation and beginign of destruction is kalpa (day of brahma) **= 4.32 billion years**

Age of earth according to modern radiometric data is around **4.54 billion years**(As you have quoted)

Puranas quotes that currently we are in  7 th manvantara , 28th mahayuga of current kalpa.

So age of earth =

```
= 6 * Years for Manvantara + 28 * Years for mahayuga
= 6 * 306.72mil            + 28 * 4.32 mil 
= 1.92 billion years
```

But I am not sure , why it would be roughly half estimated time by science.

Comment: thats what confusing me too...thanks for your answer.

Comment: You shouldn't just say "Puranas quotes that".  If you're getting your information from a Purana then you should cite the specific Purana.

Comment: You can add night of Brahma to that data (ie. night of Brahma after Pitri Kalpa). Total annihilation only takes place in Mahapralaya. So Kalpantak pralaya just refers to destruction of three worlds. Matter are present even in night of Brahma because pralaya itself is initiated by fire water etc. matter elements. But we cant actually say when matter got stability (ie

Comment: ...(ie. measured by modern science). It may take place just after the Pralaya or just before Swyambhu manwantara. Hence age of earth from Swyambhu manwantara is 1.92 billion. But age of matter of earth ie. after matter get stability (scientific measurement) could be 1.92 billion to (1.92+4.3) billion. ie. Age of earth may be between 1.92 billion to 6.22 billion years ago..

Answer (score 0):

1) In scriptures it is written that Lord Shiva has 27 skulls, each skull 
   representing one cycle of creation
2) The description of god is mentioned elaborately in vedas, upanishad and
    bramhasutra
3) The god created this universe / creation, in his own "image".  So for
   simplicity, it can be said, god is similar to human being
4) First there was "thought" and "thought" was with God.  So as a human being
   one is surrounded by many thoughts (lowest level).  The god being supreme
   being his "thought" is more powerful
5) the thought, has a word, the word was with god (Sound = Aum).
6) the thought is like a movie coming out of a cinema projector
7) when projector is switched off, the movie is finished
8) In this case, it is "pralaya" or with drawing of a creation
9) then god has capacity to create a new thought and new creation (new movie)
10) Lord Shiva is shown with 27 skulls, hence, 27 creations (movies) were 
    completed and we are in 28
11) the length of each creation is unknown to anyone and everyting that is 
    written is pure contemplation and it is better left best to exalted saints &
    yogis to know and comment

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.