# Where does Rig Veda states about Cyclical Nature of Creation?

Tags: vedas, scripture, history, rig-veda, creation

It is a common belief in Hinduism that the nature of creation is cyclic. Continuous creation and destruction happens in certain intervals of time. Most of such ideas are found in Puranas and also in Bhagvad Gita.

But do the Vedas also state about Cyclical nature of Creation? I've heard there is a verse in RigVeda which states about Cyclic Nature of Creation.

Where is that verse in Rig Veda and what it means?

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:history]?  There's nothing about history here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**10.190** is the Hymn to the creation in Rig Veda. In it's third verse it states sun and moon were created like that of previous creation.

> सूरय्याचन्द्रमसौ धाता यथा पूर्वमकल्पयत् I
>   दिवं च पृथ्वीं  च अंतरिक्षमथो स्वः   II  **RigVeda 10.190.3**  II
>   
>   "The Ordainer **created the sun and moon like those of previous cycles.** He formed in order Heaven and Earth, the regions of the air, and light."

Griffth translates it as:

> Dhātar, **the great Creator, then formed in due order Sun and Moon.** He formed in order Heaven and Earth, the regions of the air, and light.

Jamison and Brereton translate it as:

> The Ordainer **arranged, according to their proper order, sun and moon,** heaven and earth, midspace and sunlight.

In the above verse the main emphasis is on:

> **यथा पुर्वमकल्पयत् ।**
>   yathã purvamakalpayat ।
>   **Like that in previous creation.**

Comment: also the Nasadiya hymn Rg Veda x. 129. 1-7.

Comment: Yes, Nasadiya Sukta is a great hymn to creation. But I think it doesn't talk about cyclic nature of creation...

Comment: it does speak to it

Comment: @Sai Thank you! Here is translation of Griffth .. http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10190.htm if you want Jamison and Bereton translation... I can mail that book to you... You can come to our chat room here.. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38640/discussion-on-vedanta-and-philosophy

Comment: I really recommend reading Vedic Physics by Raja Ram Mohan Roy available in Amazon.